# Swagger/Springdoc OperationId with generic CRUD controller in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, kotlin, generics, boot

So I've been using this generic Crud Controller interface I created for multiple projects now, to automatically generate some functions (find all, paginated, deletes, etc.)

All seems to go well, until we look at the api spec. As the operationId should be unique, but all of the controller classes are using the same method name, it suffixes them with _1, _2, etc.

Anyone got an idea on how to use some information from the class T within the operationId? When I try to use it I get the error that annotations can only use compile time constants.

```
abstract class ITenantCrudController<T : ITenantCrudEntity>(
    override val service: ITenantCrudService<T>
) : ICrudController<T>(service) {


    @GetMapping("/find-all/{tenantId}")
    // use T in operationId to make sure the operationId is unique
    @Operation(summary = "Find all by tenantId", operationId = T::class.simpleName + "FindAllByTenantId")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SUPER_ADMIN') or @Security.isTenantAdminOf(#tenantId)")
    open fun findAllByTenantId(@PathVariable tenantId: String): ResponseEntity<List<ITenantCrudEntity>> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.findAllByTenantId(tenantId))
    }
}
```